# Saving Excel File not work in IIS 7 although it works in local ASP.NET App

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, iis

I tried to save the excel file with the records from database.
It works in asp.net application well.
But when I move it to the IIS server, it doesn't work.
I don't know how to debug the application from IIS.

Here is some code :

```
string str, filename;

        connection = new SqlConnection(con_dm);
        connection.Open();
        str = "SELECT * FROM Person";

        SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(str, connection);
        System.Data.DataTable dataTable = new System.Data.DataTable();

        adp.Fill(dataTable);

        if (dataTable.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            Excel.Application oXL;
            Excel._Workbook oWB;
            Excel._Worksheet oSheet;

            oXL = new Excel.Application();
            oXL.Visible = false;

            oXL.SheetsInNewWorkbook = 1;
            oWB = (Excel._Workbook)(oXL.Workbooks.Add());
            oSheet = (Excel._Worksheet)oWB.ActiveSheet;

            try
            {
                string[] colNames = new string[dataTable.Columns.Count];

                int col = 0;

                foreach (DataColumn dc in dataTable.Columns)
                    colNames[col++] = dc.ColumnName;

                char lastColumn = (char)(65 + dataTable.Columns.Count - 1);

                oSheet.get_Range("A1", lastColumn + "1").Value2 = colNames;
                oSheet.get_Range("A1", lastColumn + "1").Font.Bold = true;
                oSheet.get_Range("A1", lastColumn + "1").VerticalAlignment = Excel.XlVAlign.xlVAlignCenter;

                DataRow[] dr = dataTable.Select();

                string[,] rowData = new string[dr.Count<DataRow>(), dataTable.Columns.Count + 1];

                int rowCnt = 0;
                foreach (DataRow row in dr)
                {
                    for (col = 0; col < dataTable.Columns.Count; col++)
                    {
                        rowData[rowCnt, col] = row[col].ToString();
                    }
                    rowCnt++;
                }
                rowCnt++;
                oSheet.get_Range("A2", lastColumn + rowCnt.ToString()).Value = rowData;

                oXL.Visible = false;
                oXL.UserControl = true;

                String sNewFolderName = "Report_" + intReportId;
                filename = COMMON_FILE.SAVE_EXCEPTION_FILE_PATH + sNewFolderName + "\\" + "Exception_Person" + intReportId + "_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy_hh-mm-ss") + Extension;

                DirectoryInfo strDirectoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(COMMON_FILE.SAVE_EXCEPTION_FILE_PATH + sNewFolderName);

                if (!strDirectoryInfo.Exists)
                {
                    strDirectoryInfo.Create();
                }

// Set "Everyone" Permission to Folder
                string redirectionFolder = Convert.ToString(strDirectoryInfo);
                FileSystemAccessRule everyOne = new FileSystemAccessRule("Everyone", FileSystemRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow);
                DirectorySecurity dirSecurity = new DirectorySecurity(redirectionFolder, AccessControlSections.Group);
                dirSecurity.AddAccessRule(everyOne);
                Directory.SetAccessControl(redirectionFolder, dirSecurity);

                oSheet.SaveAs(filename);

                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(oWB);

                oXL.Quit();

                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(oSheet);
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(oWB);
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(oXL);

                oSheet = null;
                oWB = null;
                oXL = null;
                GC.GetTotalMemory(false);
                GC.Collect();
                GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
                GC.Collect();
                GC.GetTotalMemory(true);

                The excel is created and opened for insert value. We most close this excel using this system        
                Process[] localByName = Process.GetProcessesByName("EXCEL");
                foreach (Process process in localByName)
                {
                    process.Kill();
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // To write log.
                logFile.writeLog(ex.Message.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {   
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(oWB);
            }
        }
```

Anyone please help me on this.
Thanks

Comment: Please post some code

Comment: what is the path you are using to save the file..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone.

It works now. :)

This is because of folder permission.

I added the following :

```
// Set "Everyone" Permission to Folder 

string redirectionFolder = Convert.ToString(strDirectoryInfo); 
FileSystemAccessRule everyOne = new FileSystemAccessRule("Everyone", 
FileSystemRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow); DirectorySecurity 
            dirSecurity = new DirectorySecurity(redirectionFolder, 
            AccessControlSections.Group); 
dirSecurity.AddAccessRule(everyOne); 
Directory.SetAccessControl(redirectionFolder, dirSecurity);
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the code in try catch and print the exception, zero down on path you are saving to, it might change in a IIS context when compared with asp.net development server environment

Comment: Yes, netraju. I already put in try catch. It works in asp.net application. I thought that this is because of permission ?

Comment: Can you do this in catch
    Response.Write(ex.Message.ToString());

Comment: Thanks Raj. :) I got it. This is because of Permission.